# Setting an environment variable in a git alias

Tags: bash, git, unix

If I wanted to set the value of `foo` to equal "bar" every time I used `git status`, how would I proceed to do this? My first thought would be to set an alias for `status="status && foo=bar"` but when I attempt that and `echo $foo`, I do not get "bar" echoed; however, if I type it all out manually as `git status && foo=baz` and then `echo $foo`, my output is "baz'. Why can't I declare the variable inside the alias?

I've observed that if I were to switch the order up and for some reason do this `alias git="foo=bar && git"` and if I tried any git command and `echo foo` it equals "bar".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git aliases are run by:

- Git itself, if the alias does not start with `!`: in this case you cannot set new environment variables; or
- a POSIX-compatible shell, if the alias starts with `!`.

POSIX-compatible shells allow setting environment variables in two ways:

```
VAR=value command
```

or:

```
VAR=value; export VAR; command1; command2; ...; commandN
```

This second variant can be written as:

```
export VAR=value; command1; ...; commandN
```

The explicitly exported variable is set for *all* the commands invoked this way—versus the `VAR=value command`, which sets it just for the one command—because this setting is done *in* the shell, and persists until the shell itself exits, and then the setting disappears with the shell that has exited.  So if `x` is a Git alias:

```
git x
```

runs that alias, which can set an environment variable setting for the duration of any commands the alias itself runs.  Then the shell that is running those commands exits, and all settings evaporate.

It's therefore literally impossible for a Git alias to set any environment variable in the command-line shell you use to *run* that alias.  This is true for *all* commands, not just Git commands: no command can set environment variables in any "outer" shell.

There is one escape hatch, which is this: when you write a shell command yourself, you have control.  For instance, you can write the rather silly shell command:

```
export VAR=$(echo value)
```

where the parenthesized `$(echo value)` is evaluated and then its output is substituted in.  But this does mean that if some program *prints* some value you would like to *save*, you can write:

```
var=$(command)
```

which sets the local shell variable `var` to the output, or:

```
export VAR=$(command)
```

which sets the shell variable and exports it.  (Note: the uppercase here is merely convention: local shell variables that are exported are conventionally written in all uppercase, while local shell variables that are *not* exported are conventionally written in all lowercase.)

There is a second escape hatch as well, but using it is risky: POSIX shells have an `eval` command which feeds text back to the shell interpreter.  We can use this with programs that print `export VAR1=value1; export VAR2=value2` as their output:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Here, the `ssh-agent` program sets up the agent and then prints several appropriate `export` commands.  However, should the `ssh-agent` program print `rm -rf /`, using `eval ssh-agent -s` will proceed to remove every file it can: this means you are placing a tremendous amount of trust on that `ssh-agent` command.

You can use a *shell* alias to make some easy-to-type-in command, such as `gst`, consist of both a variable-setting operation and a Git command:

```
alias gst='foo=bar && git status'
```

This is not a *Git* alias.  This is a *shell* alias.  [POSIX now requires shell aliases](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) (thanks to KamilCuk for the pointer).  Bash always has them, though some very old non-bash shells might not have them.

Comment: Great answer! `Not all POSIX-compatible shells have shell aliases.` Ugh, so nitpicking: fun fact: alias is part of posix https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01 , so a posix compatible shell has to have aliases. Dunno, maybe alias wasn't there in older posix.

Comment: @KamilCuk: interesting. Old /bin/sh on many older systems do not have aliases. I'll update the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

- Regarding your shell's behavior :

If you write the following script :

```
# test.sh:
#!/bin/bash

foo=bar
echo "from script: $foo"
```

and you run it, you will see the following :

```
$ ./test.sh && echo "from cli: $foo"
from script: bar
from cli:
```

running the script creates a fresh, new process with its own environment, `foo=bar` gets defined in that environment, and gets thrown away once the process exits.

---

To define set that variable *in your current shell*, you have to use other ways.

@torek mentioned :

- calling `eval ...` with the output of your script
- creating a shell alias

I'll also add :

- invoke *a function* rather than a script :

```
$ mytest () {
   foo=bar
   echo "from function: $foo"
}

$ mytest && echo "from cli: $foo"
from function: bar
from cli: bar
```

---

- Regarding git aliases :

git alias will always be executed as separate processes, you will have to use some other construct if you want to set an env variable that "outlives" the invocation.

You can for example define a function in your `.bashrc` :

```
mystatus () {
    git status && foo=bar
}
```

after that, you will be able to call `mystatus` from any shell you start.

If the command is that simple, it is really equivalent to a bash alias, the upside is that it will be easier to expand the content of that function if you need to.